# Invalid parameter 'vlan' with QEMU in GNS3

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I'm new with GNS3 and qemu and need to use this tools.
I need to use a existing project GNS3 but have a problem with QEMU.

When I try to launch the GNS3 project I recive this error:

```
QEMU process has stopped, return code: 1
Start QEMU with /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name Bob -m 256M -smp cpus=1 -enable-kvm -machine smm=off -boot order=c -drive file=/home/name/GNS3/projects/LabCybersecurity/project-files/qemu/c38ee3b0-8557-4d69-b9ce-318fdd23810a/hda_disk.qcow2,if=ide,index=0,media=disk -uuid c38ee3b0-8557-4d69-b9ce-318fdd23810a -serial telnet:127.0.0.1:5006,server,nowait -monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:44319,server,nowait -net none -net nic,vlan=0,macaddr=00:4c:72:81:0a:00,model=e1000 -net socket,vlan=0,name=gns3-0,udp=127.0.0.1:10065,localaddr=127.0.0.1:10064 -vga none -vnc none

Execution log:
qemu-system-x86_64: Invalid parameter 'vlan'
```

How can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "vlan" parameter to -net was deprecated in QEMU 2.9.0 and removed in a subsequent release. You need to update your command line not to use it. Here's the text of the manual about this deprecation:

> The "-net vlan=NN" argument was mostly used to attach separate network
>   backends to different virtual NICs.  This is the default behavior for
>   "-netdev" and "-nic".  You can connect multiple "-netdev" and "-nic"
>   devices to the same network using the "hubport" network backend,
>   created with "-netdev hubport,hubid=NN,..." and "-nic
>   hubport,hubid=NN".

So depending on what you're trying to do, you might want either to just drop the vlan parameter, or else replace it with something involving hubports.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but I preferred to downgrade QEMU version for work with gns3